# Flutter/Dart Decode HttpClientResponse

Tags: http, flutter, asynchronous, dart, utf-8

I am trying to read the body of an http-response in Flutter and don't know what I'm doing wrong

In my code I'm trying to do:

```dart
static Future<String> getBody(HttpClientResponse response) async{
  return await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join('');
}
```

Without the transform, I get an array of numbers.
But when I run it with the transform I get:

```
 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception:
 FormatException: Missing extension byte (at offset 25) E/flutter (
 8628): #0      _Utf8Decoder.convertChunked
 (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1887:7) E/flutter ( 8628): #1  
 _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:314:28) E/flutter ( 8628): #2    
 _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:310:5) E/flutter ( 8628): #3      _ConverterStreamEventSink.add
 (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18) E/flutter ( 8628): #4    
 _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:121:24) E/flutter ( 8628): #5    
 _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47) E/flutter ( 8628): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19) E/flutter ( 8628): #7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7) E/flutter ( 8628): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData
 (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11) E/flutter ( 8628): #9     
 _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7) E/flutter ( 8628): #10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add
 (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:127:11) E/flutter ( 8628): #11    
 _HandleErrorStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:266:10) E/flutter ( 8628): #12     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData
 (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13) E/flutter ( 8628): #13    
 _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47) E/flutter ( 8628): #14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19) E/flutter ( 8628): #15     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7) E/flutter ( 8628): #16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData
 (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11) E/flutter ( 8628): #17    
 _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:611:14) E/flutter ( 8628): #18     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext
 (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:730:11) E/flutter ( 8628): #19    
 _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:687:7) E/flutter ( 8628): #20    
 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47) E/flutter ( 8628): #21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19) E/flutter ( 8628): #22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7) E/flutter ( 8628): #23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23) E/flutter ( 8628): #24     _rootRun
 (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13) E/flutter ( 8628): #25    
 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19) E/flutter ( 8628): #26     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7) E/flutter ( 8628): #27     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23) E/flutter ( 8628): #28    
 _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21) E/flutter ( 8628): #29     _startMicrotaskLoop
 (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

I'm using the newest version of the internal dart:io package.

Comment: Apparently the server's response isn't valid utf8. Were you expecting it to be?